# javascript problem doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having some problems.

My page is failing in this javascript code (the second line):

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
```

It is telling me:

> 'theForm.onsubmit' is null or not an
>   object.

Any ideas please?

Thanks !
C

Comment: Did you tweak the aspx or you are using the html generated by ASP.Net? Can you post the full HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure that your markup (html) form tag has runat="server"

Comment: thats in the master page and yes it has runat="server"

Comment: Can you make sure it is correctly placed inside the Body tag? It is better if you can post master page markup..